# MySQL multiple tag selection

Tags: mysql

First, sorry if the title doesn't make sense, I couldn't come up with any better. I tried to search for similar questions, but didn't find any that could help me.

**Brief description:**
I have a database of products. The products have multiple tags. I want to filter the products with the available tags. I have a solution that is already working, but it shows signs of weakness with only 40k rows in the table. I want to optimise the underlying query, so it doesn't hurt me in the long run.

**The table with the tag-item relationship:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tags_assoc` (
  `assoc_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`assoc_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**The way the page is supposed to work:**

1. There is a huge list of tags. The user chooses a `tag_id` and the
   page is filtered to only show the `item_id`s tagged with that
   certain `tag_id`.
2. The backend examines the filtered `item_id`s and lists all the
   `tag_id`s that are available for further filtering.

**Query1 - list of items:**

```
SELECT 
  item_id, 
  count(tag_id) as count 
FROM 
  tags_assoc 
WHERE 
  tag_id IN (...) 
GROUP BY 
  item_id 
HAVING
  count = (...)
```

**Query2 - list of remaining tags:**

```
SELECT
  ta.tag_id,
  t.tag_name,
  COUNT(ta.tag_id) as count
FROM
  tags_assoc ta
LEFT JOIN
  tags t ON (ta.tag_id = t.tag_id) 
WHERE 
  AND item_id IN (...)
  AND ta.tag_id NOT IN (...)
GROUP BY
  ta.tag_id
```

**How it works:**
Let's say in the first round we choose `tag_id = 250`. This means Query1 will contain `WHERE tag_id IN (250)` and `HAVING count = 1`.
The returned list will contain the following item_ids `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Now to get the remaining tags we run Query2 with the following parameters: `AND item_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND ta.tag_id NOT IN (250)`.

The users chooses an other tag from the remaining ones, let's say `tag_id = 300`. This means Query1 will contain `WHERE tag_id IN (250, 300)` and `HAVING count = 2`.
The returned list will contain the following item_ids `1, 2, 3`.

To get the remaining tags we run Query2 with the following parameters: `AND item_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND ta.tag_id NOT IN (250, 300)`.

**The problem:**
When the user chooses the first tag, the returned item_id list can be quite long. This means that Query2 will be long too as it can contain the following: `AND item_id IN (1, 2, 3, ... 7500, 7501, 7502)`. I had 37k character long queries. Regarding performance, it is not horrible, but it can cause hiccups. And this is with only 7k row in items table and 40k rows.

**What I've already tried:**
I rewrote Query2 not to contain the long item_id list, but instead use a sub-query much like the one in Query1: `AND item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM tags_assoc WHERE tag_id IN (...) GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(tag_id) = (...))`. Performance wise it was horrible, so I abandoned this alternative.

**Can someone guide me to a better direction?**
Sorry for the long post, I hope I made the problem as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to hold the output from Q1 in a temporary table, and then use this to improve the efficiency of Q2.

I've used an INNER JOIN to the temp table to filter Q2, though a subquery would be an option as well.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempQ1
(
  item_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);

INSERT INTO tempQ1
SELECT 
  item_id, 
  count(tag_id) as count 
FROM 
  tags_assoc 
WHERE 
  tag_id IN (...) 
GROUP BY 
  item_id 
HAVING
  count = (...);

-- Output tempQ1 as the first result
SELECT item_id FROM tempQ1;

SELECT
  ta.tag_id,
  t.tag_name,
FROM
  tags_assoc ta
LEFT JOIN tags t ON (ta.tag_id = t.tag_id) 
INNER JOIN tempQ1 ON ta.item_id = tempQ1.item_id
WHERE 
  ta.tag_id NOT IN (...)
GROUP BY
  ta.tag_id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempQ1;
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem with this method shows with multiple tag_ids. For example Query 1 will look like this: `SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM tags_assoc ta WHERE ta.tag_id IN (250, 300)`. This lists every item_id with **at least one of these** tags. I want to list the item_ids which has **all of these** tags. Your method widens the selection, my method narrows it. At least this is how I interpret it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - that explains the HAVING clause!

Comment: I've altered the answer to suggest using a temporary table, which I believe may help. If this doesn't solve the issue, I'll vote to delete this answer seeing as I misunderstood the original queries.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work this way. Thank you for your help anyway!